# What is the significance of word Global in the Program Global Area in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The Program Global Area (PGA) is a private memory region that contains the data and control information for a server process.There is one PGA for each server process , so when this region is reserved for each user process connecting to an Oracle Database so why is this memory called Program Global Area , what is global in this memory area ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Global" means the entire memory region allocated to a process. This entire region is subdivided into smaller regions dedicated to specific uses **by that process**: stack space (to hold stack frames), hash area (to hold hash tables created in the process of performing hash joins, or hash aggregation, etc.), bitmap merge area (to merge data from scans of bitmap indexes), and - depending on database configuration - other things, such as space for sorting, private SQL area, etc.

Each of these dedicated memory regions (and structures) has a specific name. When we need to refer to the entire memory region allocated to a process, we call that the "global" area.

For example, when we disconnect from the database, "the memory allocated to the session" is de-allocated. Technically, what does that mean? Answer: the **entire** program **global** area for that process is de-allocated. We need a term to distinguish the totality of the memory allocated to that process from the sub-regions dedicated specifically to different uses. It makes good sense to use the technical term "global" for this - well, *global* - region. ("Global", that is, from the point of view of one process - not of the entire instance.)